# initialization phases - can this be done more easily?

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization

I've a class implementing MultipeerConnectivity and I want a subclass to implement it for advertisers.  Here is what I'd like:

```
class ConnectionManager: NSObject {

  let serviceType: String
  let peerID: MCPeerID
  let session: MCSession
  var delegate: ViewController!

  override init() {
    serviceType = "mc-service"
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
    super.init()
    session.delegate = self
  }
}

class AdvertiserConnectionManager: ConnectionManager {

  let assistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant

  override init() {
    assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: serviceType, discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
    super.init()
    assistant.delegate = self
    assistant.start()
  }
}
```

but this breaks the phasing rules for init() because *MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:, discoveryInfo:, session:)* uses *serviceType* and *session*, both properties of the superclass.

I've done the following with the subclass instead, cheating by declaring *assistant* lazily.  This works!  Why?  The initialiser still needs to invoke *self*!!!  And I've had to do this unnatural thing to create my subclass. And I've probably subverted what phasing was intended to avoid!!

```
class AdvertiserConnectionManager: ConnectionManager {

  lazy var assistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant = {
    MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: serviceType, discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
  }()

  override init() {
    super.init()
    assistant.delegate = self
    assistant.start()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not *cheating* and this is not an *unnatural thing*. This is an usual way to initialize properties of an object which depend on each other.

From the [documentation (Swift Language Guide: Properties)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254):

> A *lazy stored* property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used.
>   ...
>   Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an instance’s initialization is complete.

In your case `assistant` will be initialized **after** the `super.init` call when `self`, `serviceTime` and `session` are valid and available.